# how to check which port is being used to send emails?

Tags: php, apache, logging, smtp, sendmail

Emails are processing very slowly and on an average of 500 / 20 minute. and there is a queue of 40000 yet to be send.

How to check which port is being used. There are two ports 25 and 26. I am not sure how to check which port is being used.

Also how to check where SMTP error log is located.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: soemtimes 26 is also used... how can I confirm which port is being used.

Comment: This is not a programming related question, off topic..

Comment: it is related to PHP mailer.... how can this go off th topic. anyways, please help me...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using telnet (same command for Windows and Linux):

```
telnet domain.com 25

telnet domain.com 26
```

The port that gives a 220 response is the one used. (use localhost as the domain if your not connecting from a remote computer )

You can use an IP address instead of a domain if you want to. You need to enable telnet in newer windows versions btw, it's disabled by default.

Comment: I am using apache and php.... can you please tell me how to get that.

Comment: Do you mean how to get the error logs? If it's a linux server, it should be in /var/log/mail.err  or /var/log/maillog

Comment: no.. not error logs. smtp logs and how to check which port is currently in use?

Comment: well.. the example above is for connecting to the server from a remote computer and finding out which port is used for smtp. They aren't both used, are they? Updated the post with additional info.